# I wrote socket programm which sends message from server to clinent, but doesn't work over WAN PUBLIC INTERNET

Tags: python, sockets, networking

SO I wrote 2 program::server.py and client.py
It works fine on my pc and I think it will also on LAN PRIVATE NETOWRK
But I've heard that public IP address is assigned for a Wifi router/modem, so how should the program know on which specific device of public ip it should send info to?
I asked bit unclear sorry, I'm not a native speaker
I'll ask shortly: how to edit this code for public connection?

```
    #server.py:
import socket
import pyautogui
server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind(("192.168.1.56",2101))#private IP adress
        
server.listen(5)


klienti , addr = server.accept()
asdf = pyautogui.prompt("mesiji:")
klienti.send(bytes(asdf,"utf-8"))

#client.py:
import socket
import pyautogui

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.connect(("192.168.1.56",2101))

mesiji = server.recv(1024)
pyautogui.alert(mesiji.decode("utf-8"))
```

Comment: A device inside a local network behind a NAT device can establish a connection to an outside public server, and then both can communicate. A device from outside the LAN cannot establish a connection to a device inside the LAN, unless a specific public port on the NAT device is mapped to that device.

Answer (score -1):

change line 3 to:
`server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET6,socket.SOCK_STREAM)`

and in line 4 put your public ip address instead.

Comment: thanks but, isn't that ipv6? ok but how should I get my public ip6 address?

Comment: i want it on ipv4 adress

Comment: but is your ipv4 address public? As far as I know if you want to make your server public you will have to use ipv6 address.

Comment: but i don't have ipv6, and most people don't , I want it on ipv4

Comment: see if you host a server on ipv4, all devices which are connected to the same router will be able to communicate with the server but if you want it to be public then you will have to host it on ipv6. That is as far as I know.

Comment: IPv6 is routable without NAT, but IPv6 devices aren’t automagically public. If there’s a router involved, and there usually is, it usually has an IPv6 firewall, which replaces the inherent protection of NAT for IPv4.